# Python finding multiple strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I've a list `['test_x', 'text', 'x']`. Is there any way to use regex in python to find if the string inside the list contains either `'_x' or 'x'`?

'x' should be a single string and not be part of a word without _.

The output should result in ['test_x', 'x'].

Thanks.

Comment: Is using regex a necessity? You can do the same thing with a one-line list comprehension

Comment: Regex is not necessary.

Comment: It looks like you are looking to filter a list. A regex may or may not be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using one line comprehension:

```
l = ['test_x', 'text', 'x']

result = [i for i in l if '_x' in i or 'x' == i]
```

Comment: TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: Op says the word contains _x or x

Comment: `'x' == i ` is needed since I don't want words which has x in between. Only _x or if str itself is x. Answer works though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp this way:

```
import re
print(list(filter(lambda x: re.findall(r'_x|^x$',x),l)))
```

The regexp searches for exact patterns ('_x' or 'x') within each element of the list.  applies the func to each element of the iterable.

You can make your expression more genric this way:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: re.findall(r'[^A-Za-z]x|^\W*x\W*$',x),l)))
```

Here am telling python to search for expressions which DON't start with A to Z or a to z but end in x OR search for expressions that start and end with 0 or more non-word characters but have x in between. You can refer this quick cheatsheet on regular expressions https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/python

Answer (score 0):

```
[re.findall('x|_x', s) for s in your_list]
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.